# Why can't I capture events from an extended EventEmitter class in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I've been banging my head against why I can't capture events emitted from this code in Node.js.  My gut feeling is something is out of scope, but I can't figure out what it is.  The `console.log` line of code in `index.js` never gets executed.  Is my event not being emitted?

player.js

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

class rocketPlayer extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }

  update(connection) {
    //do some logic with playlists
    this.play(connection);
  }

  play(connection) {
    // do some stuff
    this.emit('nowPlaying',song.title);
  }
}

module.exports = rocketPlayer
```

index.js

```
const rocketPlayer = require('./player.js');
const player = new rocketPlayer();

player.on('nowPlaying', title => {
  console.log('caught nowPlaying event');
});

//define a connection
player.update(connection)
```

Comment: Stick some logs inside your `update` and `play` methods. Inheriting from EventEmitter is done as it should be.

Comment: Where are you calling `.emit('nowPlaying', {})`

Comment: I've got some logging in the play function, its after the emit call and it comes out without error. It's driving me nuts that the event isn't being captured though.

Comment: What does `console.log(this)` say right after the emit call? I would assume the `// do some stuff` is the culprit. Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 2):

you have a few typos: You are missing a bracket after your listener. You also don't pass the constructor arguments down to the super constructor properly. Following code works for me:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

class rocketPlayer extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }

  update(connection) {
    //do some logic with playlists
    this.play(connection);
  }

  play(connection) {
    // do some stuff
    this.emit('nowPlaying', 'song.title');
  }
}

const player = new rocketPlayer();

player.on('nowPlaying', title => {
  console.log('caught nowPlaying event');
}); // <= fixed missing bracket

//define a connection
player.update('connection');
```

Note: as you didn't define song i just converted it into a string

Comment: Typos in my original post aside, your code doesn't implement the separate files and modules.export method, which I need.

Comment: that should work like you posted. i put it in one file for testing purposes only

Comment: then you would get some error like cannot find module player. this is clearly not the root of your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you had a few things wrong with your example as posted; notably the song method as written was throwing an exception.

player.js:

```
"use strict";
let EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

class RocketPlayer extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }

  update(connection) {
    //do some logic with playlists
    this.play(connection);
  }

  play(song) {
    // do some stuff
    this.emit('nowPlaying', song.title);
  }
}

module.exports = RocketPlayer;
```

index.js:

```
const RocketPlayer = require('./player.js');
const player = new RocketPlayer();

const connection = {title: "Boooboo!"};

player.on('nowPlaying', title => {
  console.log('caught nowPlaying event', title);
});

//define a connection
player.update(connection);
```

result:

```
PS D:\Code\data> node -v
v7.4.0
PS D:\Code\data> node ./index
caught nowPlaying event Boooboo!
```

Comment: I went back to the code and realized that I had been editing a file that was buffered in memory in my IDE and it somehow restored it on the drive after I had renamed some project files, so every edit I made was not being referenced in my main loop.  I've got it working now, thank you for your help.